# How to manage your own user context on Windows files?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, file, ownership

I am working on a Windows 8.1/10-based Kiosk-type product (closed-down, no Windows GUI). We have our own user management system where every user of the Kiosk has to log on. Windows-wise the user is always the same auto logged on one, for reasons beyond my control.

In the process after logging on, files will be created. As the Windows user is always one and the same, the owner of created files will always be the same. How would I go about applying some kind of user context/ownership indication to the created files using our own user context? The most important use of this would be to keep track of which files to show/list for which user. We use C++ and C#.

edit: This has not been a problem until now, as each user has had their files stored in their own directory. We have then used that fact for deciding what files to show to a user. We are now changing that to instead let certain input dictate where the files are to be created for a more flexible, custom file structure.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create a dedicated directory for each unique user who logs in?  What am I missing where this wouldn't work?

Comment: Or store the files inside the user profile if only the owner needs to have access?

Comment: I **think** the OP is saying there's exactly one unique Windows user account that is auto-logged in on startup.  Then the kiosk app starts up and has it's own shell for a user to type name/password.  He's asking how to structure something... but that's where I get lost.

Comment: Why can't you handle the user's directory like an "invisible" root directory which always internally preceeds any directory/file path presented to / created by the user?